# can' t access ec2 instance for additional user with sftp or ssh - key refused

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, sftp

I keep getting server refused our key error with putty/public key rejected error in filezilla when trying to access my ec2instance with a new user.

Access works fine for both ssh and sftp with the ec2-user user.

I have done the following.

generated new key pair in ec2 AWS for the instance in question.

sudo adduser newusername

sudo mkdir /home/newusername/.ssh

Pasted public key into /home/newusername/.ssh/authorized_keys

sudo chmod 700 /home/newusername/.ssh

sudo chmod 600 /home/newusername/.ssh/authorized_keys

sudo chown -R newusername:newusername /home/newusername/.ssh

I have deleted the keypair created a new one and gone through this again to make sure I haven't made an error in the process.

Can anyone advise what I am missing?

Running Amazon Linux.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you take a look to your /var/log/messages? Sometimes provides useful information.

Comment: @alphamikevictor Authentication logs will be in `/var/log/secure`.

Comment: just as an update: there was no additional information in these logs so the problem remains, mystified as to what it is.